# Custom implementation of the linq Zip operator for different length lists

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

Based on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53170526/5481787) I have my implementation of linq Zip operator which operates on different length lists, and loops shortest list.

My implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SO
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<String> listA = new List<string> {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"};
            List<String> listB = new List<string> {"1", "2", "3"};

            var mix = listA.ZipNew(listB, (l1, l2) => new[] {l1, l2}).SelectMany(x => x);

            foreach (var m in mix)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Impl
    {               
        public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipNew<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>( 
            this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, 
            IEnumerable<TSecond> second, 
            Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector) 
        { 
            using (IEnumerator<TFirst> iterator1 = first.GetEnumerator()) 
            using (IEnumerator<TSecond> iterator2 = second.GetEnumerator())
            {
                var i1 = true;
                var i2 = true;
                var i1Shorter = false;
                var i2Shorter = false;
                var firstRun = true;


                while(true) 
                {
                    i1 = iterator1.MoveNext();
                    i2 = iterator2.MoveNext();

                    if (!i1 && (i1Shorter || firstRun))
                    {
                        iterator1.Reset();
                        i1 = iterator1.MoveNext();
                        i1Shorter = true;
                        firstRun = false;
                    }

                    if (!i2 && (i2Shorter || firstRun))
                    {
                        iterator2.Reset();
                        i2 = iterator2.MoveNext();
                        i2Shorter = true;
                        firstRun = false;
                    }

                    if (!(i1 && i2))
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    yield return resultSelector(iterator1.Current, iterator2.Current); 
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

And I wonder if this implementation could be improved somehow, what could be improved, for better readability or speed.

Comment: Your question would benefit from some example usage within the question itself, so that we can see how you intend the method to be consumed, and quickly verify that it is working as intended.

Comment: @VisualMelon improved, full working code

Comment: Never `Reset` an enumerator. Just get a new enumerator.  `Reset` was a misfeature intended for COM interop scenarios.

Answer (score 10):

> ```
>     public static class Impl
>     {
>         public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipNew<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(
> ```

Names? The class would be more descriptive as something like `LinqExtensions`; the method something like `ZipLooped`.

---

> ```
>             using (IEnumerator<TFirst> iterator1 = first.GetEnumerator()) 
>             using (IEnumerator<TSecond> iterator2 = second.GetEnumerator())
>             {
>                 var i1 = true;
>                 var i2 = true;
>                 var i1Shorter = false;
>                 var i2Shorter = false;
>                 var firstRun = true;
> ```

The iterators have useful names, but what does `i1` mean? And why five variables to track the state of two iterators? IMO it would be simpler as

```
                var firstEnded = false;
                var secondEnded = false;

                while (true) 
                {
                    if (!iterator1.MoveNext())
                    {
                        if (secondEnded) yield break;
                        firstEnded = true;
                        iterator1.Reset();
                        if (!iterator1.MoveNext()) yield break;
                    }
                    if (!iterator2.MoveNext())
                    {
                        if (firstEnded) yield break;
                        secondEnded = true;
                        iterator2.Reset();
                        if (!iterator2.MoveNext()) yield break;
                    }

                    yield return resultSelector(iterator1.Current, iterator2.Current); 
                }
```

and the almost repeated code *might* be worth pulling out as an inner method:

```
                var firstEnded = false;
                var secondEnded = false;

                bool advance<T>(IEnumerator<T> it, ref bool thisEnded, bool otherEnded)
                {
                    if (it.MoveNext()) return true;
                    // `it` has done a full cycle; if the other one has too, we've finished
                    if (otherEnded) return false;
                    thisEnded = true;
                    // Start again, although if `it` is empty we need to abort
                    it.Reset();
                    return it.MoveNext();
                }

                while (true)
                {
                    if (!advance(iterator1, ref firstEnded, secondEnded)) yield break;
                    if (!advance(iterator2, ref secondEnded, firstEnded)) yield break;
                    yield return resultSelector(iterator1.Current, iterator2.Current); 
                }
```

---

I notice that you've decided to `yield break` if either of the enumerables is empty. Would an exception be a better choice?

Comment: I'd rename `advance` in `TryMoveNextOrLoop`

Comment: _I notice that you've decided to yield break if either of the enumerables is empty._ - This is the expected behaviour. I'd be surprised if it was something else and this makes linq so reliable - nothing there so nothing happens - otherwise you would need to check everything for emptyness, not pretty ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t only most LINQ methods don't explicitly loop over one of the inputs as it consumes the other. I would probably expect an exception here if only one of them was empty, and an empty enumerable (`yield break`) if both are empty.

Comment: @VisualMelon no way :-P this is not how it should work. No collection returning LINQ extensions throw exceptions if the source is empty. Compare this `new[] { 1 }.Zip(Enumerable.Empty<int>(), (x, y) => (x, y)).Dump();` The result is an empty collection.

Comment: @t3chb0t indeed, but that's because it's defined as zipping as far as the shortest. I'd argue that extracting values repeatedly from an empty collection is meaningless, and so it should throw (as per `Average`). Anyhow, I can see your argument, so I think we'll have to agree to disagree :P

Comment: @t3chb0t, `advance` here is an inner method, so it feels strange to me to give it a name with a leading capital letter. The reason that an exception makes sense to me is that the behaviour here should be that if the longer enumerable has length \$n\$ and the shorter has length \$m\$ the shorter should be repeated \$n/m\$ times, which gives a division by zero.

Comment: @VisualMelon I disagree to agree to disagree ;-] `Avarage`, `Min` or `Max` are scalars, that's why I said _collection returning LINQ extensions_ - I'm ok with them to throw but not when it's a non-scalar. This would make concatenating them very unpredictable... although I have to admit I already created `AverageOrDefault` etc because those scalars a real traps.

Comment: I've posted [my](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53417215/235671) version under the original question - which is basically the same as yours. Maybe I'll get some internet points too ;-]

Comment: Mhmm... could you explain what you mean with the division by zero in other words? I'm not sure why this is relevant... especially that you are not dividing anything.

Comment: @t3chb0t, in the example the longer list has 7 elements and the shorter list has 3 elements, so the shorter list is repeated 7/3 times. If the shorter list had 0 elements, it should be repeated 7/0 times. From a different perspective, I understand the requirement to be that `a.ZipNew(b, _).Count() == Math.Max(a.Count(), b.Count())`, so if one of them is empty the method cannot fulfil its contract (unless both of them are empty - VisualMelon made a good point there).

Comment: I see your point now, thanks for reframing it... however, one could say the same about the original `Zip` - your example would apply there too and yet they've decided to no throw when one collection is empty and I think it was a good decision. Not throwing is always better then throwing. `7/0` would be acceptable for something like `ZipLoopedOrEmpty` or `ZipLoopedOrDefault` but not for this one. I have large system build on top of this behaviour and I would be very unhappy if I had to check each collection for emptyness first. This would kill the 30+ calls spread over multiple methods chain;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t, no. If you could say the same about `Zip` then this method would be unnecessary. `a.Zip(b, _).Count() == Math.Min(a.Count(), b.Count())` and the difference between `Min` and `Max` in the presence of `0` is the crucial point.

Answer (score 10):

I noticed a few things that can be improved:

- Not all enumerators support `Reset`. Generator methods don't, for example, so calling `ZipNew` on the result of a `ZipNew` call will fail with a `NotSupportedException`. Obtaining a new enumerator should work, at the cost of having to replace the convenient `using` statements with `try/finally` constructions. ***Edit***: As Eric pointed out, `Reset` should not be used at all. It's been abandoned.
- There's no need to call `Reset` *(or rather, to get a new enumerator)* when a collection is empty. I'd probably add a special case for that.
- Passing `null` causes either an unspecific `NullReferenceException` or an `ArgumentNullException` with parameter name `source` to be thrown. Throwing `ArgumentNullException`s with accurate parameter names would be more helpful. ***Edit:*** As JAD pointed out, this is trickier than it looks. You'll have to split the method into an eager non-yielding method and a lazy yielding method. A local function should be useful here.
- `i1` and `i2` can be declared inside the while loop.

---

**Addendum:**

As Henrik's answer shows, a helper class can be useful for properly repeating enumerators without having to give up on `using`. I would take a slightly different approach by creating a repeatable enumerator class:

```
class RepeatableEnumerator<T> : IDisposable
{
    private IEnumerable<T> _enumerable;
    private IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;


    public bool IsRepeating { get; private set; }
    public T Current => _enumerator.Current;


    public RepeatableEnumerator(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        _enumerable = enumerable;
        _enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _enumerator.Dispose();
        _enumerator = null;
    }

    public bool MoveNext() => _enumerator.MoveNext();

    public bool Repeat()
    {
        IsRepeating = true;
        _enumerator.Dispose();
        _enumerator = _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
        return _enumerator.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Which can then be used for both enumerables (and possibly in other extension methods as well):

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipLongest<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
    IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    // Eager parameter validation:
    if (first == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(first));
    if (second == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(second));
    if (resultSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resultSelector));

    // Local function for lazy zipping:
    IEnumerable<TResult> ZipLongestImpl()
    {
        using (var enum1 = new RepeatableEnumerator<TFirst>(first))
        using (var enum2 = new RepeatableEnumerator<TSecond>(second))
        {
            // Up-front check for empty collections:
            if (!enum1.MoveNext() || !enum2.MoveNext())
                yield break;

            while (true)
            {
                yield return resultSelector(enum1.Current, enum2.Current);

                var is1Empty = !enum1.MoveNext();
                var is2Empty = !enum2.MoveNext();
                if (is1Empty)
                {
                    if (enum2.IsRepeating || is2Empty || !enum1.Repeat())
                        yield break;
                }
                else if (is2Empty)
                {
                    if (enum1.IsRepeating || !enum2.Repeat())
                        yield break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ZipLongestImpl();
}
```

At this point it would be a good idea to add some documentation...

Comment: Worth adding that if you're going to throw `ArgumentNullExceptions`, make sure they're thrown eagerly, not only when iteration has started.

Comment: That's a good point! Much trickier than you'd expect it to be... looks like a good place to use a local function.

Comment: Ah, so that's what you meant with a local function. If you look at what [`System.Linq`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,24) does, they put the lazy part in a separate private method. But I don't think there's much difference between those two.

Comment: Also, maybe it's worth adding a repetition counter to the repeater class. I can imagine some instances where it's worth knowing howmany time it has looped.

Comment: Local functions get turned into private static methods, so it's basically the same thing. I think they would've been used in Linq if they had been available at that time. I'll update the example to use capturing though - contrary to what I expected, in this case it's actually slightly faster, and it simplifies the code a little.

Comment: Ah, good to know. Never used local functions before.

Answer (score 7):

If you should respect that not all `Enumerators` implement `Reset()` then it is not possible to use `using` statements for the two `IEnumerators`. But you could introduce an `IEnumerator<TResult>` for the zipped result and use it like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipNew<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(
this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector)
{
  if (first == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(first));
  if (second == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(second));
  if (resultSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resultSelector));

  return InnerZipNew(first, second, resultSelector);
}

private static IEnumerable<TResult> InnerZipNew<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(
this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector)
{
  using (ZipEnumerator<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> zipEnumerator = new ZipEnumerator<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(first, second, resultSelector))
  {
    while (zipEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
      yield return zipEnumerator.Current;
    }
  }
}
```

As JAD writes in his comment it is necessary to catch possible invalid input as the first thing and then call a private shadow method to do the actual iteration in order to make the exceptions be thrown when the extension is called rather than when the enumeration is performed.

In this way you're back on the using track.

The `ZipEnumerator` it self could be something like:

```
  public class ZipEnumerator<T, S, TResult> : IEnumerator<TResult>
  {
    IEnumerable<T> m_dataT;
    IEnumerable<S> m_dataS;
    IEnumerator<T> m_enumerT;
    IEnumerator<S> m_enumerS;
    List<IDisposable> m_disposables = new List<IDisposable>();
    Func<T, S, TResult> m_selector;
    bool m_secondReloaded = false;
    bool m_first = true;

    public ZipEnumerator(IEnumerable<T> dataT, IEnumerable<S> dataS, Func<T, S, TResult> selector)
    {
      m_dataT = dataT ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataT));
      m_dataS = dataS ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataS));
      m_selector = selector ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));

    }

    public TResult Current => m_selector(m_enumerT.Current, m_enumerS.Current);

    object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

    public void Dispose()
    {
      foreach (IDisposable disposable in m_disposables)
      {
        disposable.Dispose();
      }
      m_disposables.Clear();
    }

    private IEnumerator<T> GetTEnumerator()
    {
      var enumerator = m_dataT.GetEnumerator();
      m_disposables.Add(enumerator);
      return enumerator;
    }

    private IEnumerator<S> GetSEnumerator()
    {
      var enumerator = m_dataS.GetEnumerator();
      m_disposables.Add(enumerator);
      return enumerator;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
      m_enumerT = m_enumerT ?? GetTEnumerator();
      m_enumerS = m_enumerS ?? GetSEnumerator();

      if (m_first)
      {
        if (m_enumerT.MoveNext())
        {
          if (!m_enumerS.MoveNext())
          {
            m_enumerS = GetSEnumerator();
            m_secondReloaded = true;
            if (!m_enumerS.MoveNext())
              return false;
          }
          return true;
        }
        else
        {
          m_first = false;
        }
      }

      if (!m_first && !m_secondReloaded)
      {
        if (m_enumerS.MoveNext())
        {
          if (!m_enumerT.MoveNext())
          {
            m_enumerT = GetTEnumerator();
            if (!m_enumerT.MoveNext())
              return false;
          }

          return true;
        }
      }

      return false;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
      m_secondReloaded = false;
      m_first = true;
      m_enumerT = null;
      m_enumerS = null;
      Dispose();
    }
  }
```

It's a little more code than other suggestions, but it encapsulates the problems with the disposal of intermediate enumerators without the necessity of a try-catch-statement. You could discuss if the disposal should be immediately when the enumerator is done or as I do collect them for disposal when the `ZipEnumerator` itself is disposed off?

The `MoveNext()` method went a little more complicated than I like, so feel free to edit or suggest improvements.

---

**Edit**

A refactored version of `ZipEnumerator`:

```
  public class ZipEnumerator<T, S, TResult> : IEnumerator<TResult>
  {
    IEnumerable<T> m_dataT;
    IEnumerable<S> m_dataS;
    IEnumerator<T> m_enumeratorT;
    IEnumerator<S> m_enumeratorS;
    List<IDisposable> m_disposables = new List<IDisposable>();
    Func<T, S, TResult> m_selector;
    bool m_secondReloaded = false;
    bool m_isInitilized = false;

    public ZipEnumerator(IEnumerable<T> dataT, IEnumerable<S> dataS, Func<T, S, TResult> selector)
    {
      m_dataT = dataT ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataT));
      m_dataS = dataS ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataS));
      m_selector = selector ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));
    }

    public TResult Current => m_selector(m_enumeratorT.Current, m_enumeratorS.Current);
    object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

    public void Dispose()
    {
      DoDispose();
    }

    private void RegisterDisposable(IDisposable disposable)
    {
      m_disposables.Add(disposable);
      if (m_disposables.Count > 10)
      {
        DoDispose();
      }
    }

    private void DoDispose()
    {
      foreach (IDisposable disposable in m_disposables)
      {
        disposable.Dispose();
      }
      m_disposables.Clear();
    }

    private IEnumerator<T> GetTEnumerator()
    {
      var enumerator = m_dataT.GetEnumerator();
      RegisterDisposable(enumerator);
      return enumerator;
    }

    private IEnumerator<S> GetSEnumerator()
    {
      var enumerator = m_dataS.GetEnumerator();
      RegisterDisposable(enumerator);
      return enumerator;
    }

    private Func<bool> CurrentMover = null;

    private bool FirstMover()
    {
      if (m_enumeratorT.MoveNext())
      {
        if (!m_enumeratorS.MoveNext())
        {
          m_enumeratorS = GetSEnumerator();
          m_secondReloaded = true;
          if (!m_enumeratorS.MoveNext())
            return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
      else if (!m_secondReloaded)
      {
        CurrentMover = SecondMover;
        return CurrentMover();
      }

      return false;
    }

    private bool SecondMover()
    {
      if (m_enumeratorS.MoveNext())
      {
        if (!m_enumeratorT.MoveNext())
        {
          m_enumeratorT = GetTEnumerator();
          if (!m_enumeratorT.MoveNext())
            return false;
        }

        return true;
      }

      return false;
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
      m_enumeratorT = GetTEnumerator();
      m_enumeratorS = GetSEnumerator();
      CurrentMover = FirstMover;
      m_isInitilized = true;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
      if (!m_isInitilized)
      {
        Initialize();
      }
      return CurrentMover();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
      m_isInitilized = false;
      m_secondReloaded = false;
      CurrentMover = null;
      m_enumeratorT = null;
      m_enumeratorS = null;
      DoDispose();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'd like to click +1 but when I see the variable names it says -1 so at the and it's a 0 ;-)

Comment: I think the word _unconventional_ describes them pretty good... although `ts` and `ss` were below that level ;-]

Comment: I can explain that ;-P It's local and in a very small scope, this is allowed in my world, `tt` and `ss` on the other hand were `public`.

Comment: You might want to refactor this so that the null-checks are eagerly performed instead of when iteration start. Doing so would be in line with other Linq implementations. Calling any Linq method on a null enumerable will throw immediately, not when iterating starts. To do this, have the public extension methods check for nulls, then from that call a private method that's using the `yield return` lazy evaluation. [Example](https://gist.github.com/JarkoDubbeldam/57430846438be59f15f68a8d6ddeeea4).

Comment: @JAD: I maybe misunderstand you, but the null-checks are performed in the constructor of the ZipEnumerator - not in the MoveNext(). I leave it to the Enumerator to handle invalid input, which I find appropriate.

Comment: @HenrikHansen I saw that. The problem is that if a method is using the `yield` method of returning a `IEnumerable`, the entire method is treated as lazy. So nothing in the method starts executing before the first element in the result sequence is accessed. This means that only at that point the `ZipEnumerator` is constructed, and only then nullchecks are performed. Take a look at [this blog by Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot/) for another (probably better) explanation.

Comment: @JAD: OK, I've found the case. You got a point here. I'll update.

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved with less noise in the code. So we can have the guarding logic in the main call as follows:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TResult>> ZipManyWithDifferentLengths<TIn, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TIn>> sequences,
        Func<TIn, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        if (resultSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resultSelector));

        var sequenceCollection = sequences as IEnumerable<TIn>[] ?? sequences.ToArray();
        if (sequenceCollection.Any(_ => _ == null)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(sequences));

        return ZipIterator(sequenceCollection, resultSelector);
    }
```

We can get all the enumerators in input sequences, then, iterate through them in a way which increments a counter when MoveNext fails to do so for an enumerator. If not, we Concat results of the selector function applied to each element in that certain position in each sequence. Once the counter is equal to the number of sequences, we break the loop as there is nothing more to iterate over. Below is the code doing that all:

```
     private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TResult>> ZipIterator<TIn, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TIn>> sequences,
        Func<TIn, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        var enumerators = sequences.Select(_ => _.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
        var length = enumerators.Length;
        var counter = 0;
        while (counter < length)
        {
            var result = Enumerable.Empty<TResult>();
            foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, length))
            {
                if (!enumerators[i].MoveNext()) counter++;
                else
                {
                    result = resultSelector(enumerators[i].Current).Yield().Concat(result);
                }
            }

            yield return result;
        }
    }
```

where Yield implementation is as follows:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>(this T item)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
```

Note that we need to make sure the extention method name is not misleading considering default Zip operation semantics.

**EDIT**

Fixing obvious issues caused by wrong choice of test data which made it look like it was working - I used 3 lists of 1, 2 and 3 elements which was hiding the `counter` issue. Also adding the dispose call for each enumerator.

```
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TResult>> ZipIteratorExtended<TIn, TResult>(
            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TIn>> sequences,
            Func<TIn, TResult> resultSelector)
        {
            var enumerators = sequences.Select(_ => _.GetEnumerator()).ToList();
            var length = enumerators.Count;
            var breakEnumerators = new bool[length];
            while (breakEnumerators.Any(_ => !_))
            {
                var result = Enumerable.Empty<TResult>();
                foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, length))
                {
                    if (!enumerators[i].MoveNext()) breakEnumerators[i] = true;
                    else
                    {
                        result = resultSelector(enumerators[i].Current).Yield().Concat(result);
                    }
                }

                yield return result;
            }

            enumerators.ForEach(_ => _.Dispose());
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a few problems with this approach: it's not how `Zip` and `ZipNew`'s `resultSelector` works, it's not repeating shorter sequences, there's a bug where `counter` gets incremented too often when one sequence is shorter, and the enumerators are not being disposed.

Comment: Another point: it only makes sense to make `result` an enumerable if you want to lazily call `resultSelector`. That's not the case here, so you might as well use a list or array - less overhead and less code. As for `Yield` (which I think is an interesting approach - in the past I would just wrap the item in an array), nowadays Linq offers `Prepend` and `Append` methods.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet - Thanks for the feedback. Just shared the refactored version.